# Need to get field value by its name and name of its structure

Tags: hl7, nhapi

How can I get value of Hl7 field specifying just name of structure and filed of Hl7 message? This line of code `message.GetStructure("MSH")` works well, while this does not: `message.GetStructure("MSH.SendingFacility")`. The name of field is known in a runtime only, so I can not use strongly type methods like `message.GetStructure("MSH").SendingFacility()`.

Comment: I took a look at Hl7 spec and I guess there is no 'get by field name' method as there is no such field names defined in Hl7 spec, instead order is defined only. There is a method in NHapi letting access field value by its order which meets the spec. Correct me if I'm wrong please

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you know the field name?

NHAPI is based around the HL7 specifications.  Within the specifications all of the fields in all segments are named.

If you are adding a new field, then you should be creating a custom message definition and naming the field.

As @YMC mentioned, you can select a field using the index. Another option, although possibly not as efficient, is to traverse through all segments and fields.  Which I have done in my [NHAPI HL7 tree view application](http://github.com/dgrinberg/HL7-Snoop)

Comment: Field name is only known in run time in my case as it is something user enters in the form. 
Do I understand you correctly that field names are defined in so called message definition that is part of hl7 message and may be any string value, whatever 2 communicating organizations agreed upon, i.e. hl7 standard does not fix specific names of fields, but only orders?